# Error with npm-gyp during npm rebuild

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nvm

when I make `sudo npm rebuild` initially everything works correctly but then I get this type of error:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-63-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/.../.../node_modules/pg
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.40
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

How can I fix this issue?